# Can you break up Eldritch Blast attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

EB at higher levels makes multiple beams. Can you choose targets after each beam, move in between them, and use bonus actions as well?

Case in point, level 5 Warlock casts EB. Decides to target Alice first, hits first beam on Alice, and downs her. Warlock then moves 10ft, casts Hex on Bob with a bonus action, and hits second beam on Bob as well. Is this legal?